# How can I get this information from this .txt file and use it in my code properly (C language)

Tags: c, file-io, scanf, fgets, calculation

I need some help with my C-language coding assignment in school. I don't know how to make this code work.

The task is to input the price and calories of ingredients from a text file called "ingredientList.txt" which has fixed ingredients with the price and calories of it.

The price and calories will be under the name of the ingredients respectively.

Here is the file:

```
ingredient1
90.00
410

ingredient2
0.00
20

ingredient3
0.00
10

ingredient4
30.00
60

ingredient05
40.00
150
```

I need to input how many ingredients I want and calculate the total price and calories at the end.

Here is the input example:

```
ingredient1: 3
ingredient2: 1
ingredient3: 0
ingredient4: 4
ingredient5: 6
```

Here is what the output should be:

```
price: 630.00
calories: 2380
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct ingredients
{
     int in1,in2,in3,in4,in5;
} list;
int main()
{
     FILE *fp;
     fp=fopen("ingredientsList.txt","r");
     list in;
     int totalPrice=0,totalCalories=0,tempi,tempf;
     //tempi and tempf are used as temporary variables for integer and float variables respectively
     char name[100];
     printf("ingredient1: ");scanf("%d",&in.in1);
     printf("ingredient2: ");scanf("%d",&in.in2);
     printf("ingredient3: ");scanf("%d",&in.in3);
     printf("ingredient4: ");scanf("%d",&in.in4);
     printf("ingredient5: ");scanf("%d",&in.in5);
     //This is the part where I scan the price and calories from the file
     while(fgets(name,100,fp)!=NULL)
     //This part will scan the name of the ingredient and stop the loop if it reached the last line
     {
           if(strcmp(name,"ingredient1\n")==0)
           {
                 fscanf(fp,"%f",&tempf);
                 fscanf(fp,"%d",&tempi);
                 totalPrice+=tempf*(in.in1);
                 totalCalories+=tempi*(in.in1);
           }
           else if(strcmp(name,"ingredient2\n")==0)
           {
                 fscanf(fp,"%f",&tempf);
                 fscanf(fp,"%d",&tempi);
                 totalPrice+=tempf*(in.in2);
                 totalCalories+=tempi*(in.in2);
           }
           else if(strcmp(name,"ingredient3\n")==0)
           {
                 fscanf(fp,"%f",&tempf);
                 fscanf(fp,"%d",&tempi);
                 totalPrice+=tempf*(in.in3);
                 totalCalories+=tempi*(in.in3);
           }
           else if(strcmp(name,"ingredient4\n")==0)
           {
                 fscanf(fp,"%f",&tempf);
                 fscanf(fp,"%d",&tempi);
                 totalPrice+=tempf*(in.in4);
                 totalCalories+=tempi*(in.in4);
           }
           else if(strcmp(name,"ingredient5\n")==0)
           {
                 fscanf(fp,"%f",&tempf);
                 fscanf(fp,"%d",&tempi);
                 totalPrice+=tempf*(in.in5);
                 totalCalories+=tempi*(in.in5);
           } 
     }
     printf("price: %.2f",totalPrice);
     printf("\ncalories: %d",totalCalories);
     fclose(fp);
}
```

I inputted the input example and here's the output:

```
price: 0.00
calories: 0
```

I know the problem is in the scanning part, but I don't know how to fix it.

If you could give me some advice on this it would be a pleasure.

Edit1:
I tried debugging and found that the program doesn't run any function in the while loop, which means that the program thinks that fgets(name,100,fp)==NULL, but how is this possible and how can I fix it, and am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and step through it line by line. Or even use debug print statements to trace the program execution to check each step.

Comment: `fp=fopen("ingredientsList","r");` Add basic error checking code to check the return value of this and other functions (e.g. `fscanf`) to see if the function succeeds or not. For example, you wrote: *a text file called "ingredientList.txt"*. But you are not opening a file of that name.

Comment: Change all fscanf(fp,"%f",&tempf)/fscanf(fp,"%d",&tempi) to fscanf(fp,"price: %f",&tempf)/fscanf(fp,"calories: %d",&tempi).
This should lead to reading the right values.

Comment: @nevilad I tried it but unfortunately, the output is still the same

Comment: Then step your program in debug mode and see all the values read and calculated. Check that all reads read correct values.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared totalPrice and tempf as int:

```
int totalPrice=0,totalCalories=0,tempi,tempf;
```

Change them to float:

```
int totalCalories=0,tempi;
float totalPrice=0, tempf;
```

Total calories in your example is not 2380:
3 * 410 + 1 * 20 + 0 * 10 + 4 * 60 + 6 * 150 = 2390

There is also a typo in your ingredients.txt file, change ingredient05 to ingredient5.